# Running unsafe code with Apache Beam + Flink

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I've been investigating in Apache Beam to see if that is a solution to my problem, but I haven't found all information needed, so I though it would be good to ask.

Situation:
The user of the SaaS service can upload data and custom Python scripts and build a pipeline to execute it on that data. So the service reads the data, runs the Python script with the data as input, passes the output to next script that the user has uploaded and finally save the result in a database.

Current solution is built with a few micro services in a Kubernetes kluster using Akka Actors and a execution pod per tenant running the unsafe Python code, but we want to replace this with something else.

Need support for:

- Multi tenant: an executing Python script can't access memory or temporary files of any other executing script
- Data isolation: no input, database or intermediate data from a user/tenat should be at any time possible to read from any other user (like from the running Python script).
- Since the Python scripts could contain anything, they must be ran in an isolated environment.

Can this be solved with Apache Beam (maybe with Apache Flink as a runner) or should I look for another solution?

All hints and things to think about are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say too much about FlinkRunner but DataflowRunner is a good fit for your case. You can check [How Cloud Dataflow works and how Dataflow Job is managed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67409934/how-cloud-dataflow-works-and-how-dataflow-job-is-managed).